Elastic Search service going down - Error loading SPI class list from URL - x-pack-security
I was using Elastic Search 8.14.2, and the service would crash every week. The log output showed that x-pack-security-8.14.1 was not found, but the installed Elastic Search version was 8.14.2. I tried reinstalling Elastic Search, removing all old files and configurations. I installed version 8.14.3, but the same problem occurred, and now it complains about the x-pack-security version 8.14.2. Has anyone experienced this? Any tips?
The log output:
[2024-07-14T01:30:00,000][INFO ][o.e.x.s.SnapshotRetentionTask] [elastic-vm] starting SLM retention snapshot cleanup task

[2024-07-14T01:30:00,000][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] [elastic-vm] triggering scheduled [ML] maintenance tasks

[2024-07-14T01:30:00,005][INFO ][o.e.x.s.SnapshotRetentionTask] [elastic-vm] there are no repositories to fetch, SLM retention snapshot cleanup task complete

[2024-07-14T01:30:00,006][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [elastic-vm] Deleting expired data

[2024-07-14T01:30:00,009][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.r.UnusedStatsRemover] [elastic-vm] Successfully deleted [0] unused stats documents

[2024-07-14T01:30:00,009][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [elastic-vm] Completed deletion of expired ML data

[2024-07-14T01:30:00,010][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] [elastic-vm] Successfully completed [ML] maintenance task: triggerDeleteExpiredDataTask

[2024-07-14T02:52:37,016][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elastic-vm] fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[elastic-vm][masterService#updateTask][T#970]], exiting

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Error loading SPI class list from URL: jar:file:///usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-security/x-pack-security-8.14.2.jar!/META-INF/services/org.elas

ticsearch.index.SlowLogFieldProvider

at org.elasticsearch.plugins.spi.SPIClassIterator.loadNextProfile(SPIClassIterator.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.plugins.spi.SPIClassIterator.hasNext(SPIClassIterator.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.createExtensions(PluginsService.java:379) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadServiceProviders(PluginsService.java:334) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.loadSlowLogFieldProvider(IndicesService.java:1399) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndexService(IndicesService.java:742) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.withTempIndexService(IndicesService.java:699) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexWithTemporaryService(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexRequestForSystemIndex(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:711) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexRequest(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:374) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService.applyCreateIndexRequest(MetadataCreateIndexService.java:439) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.AutoCreateAction$TransportAction$CreateIndexTask.execute(AutoCreateAction.java:334) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.AutoCreateAction$TransportAction.lambda$new$0(AutoCreateAction.java:120) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.innerExecuteTasks(MasterService.java:1039) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:1004) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeAndPublishBatch(MasterService.java:232) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$BatchingTaskQueue$Processor.lambda$run$2(MasterService.java:1645) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.run(ActionListener.java:356) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$BatchingTaskQueue$Processor.run(MasterService.java:1642) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$5.lambda$doRun$0(MasterService.java:1237) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.run(ActionListener.java:356) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$5.doRun(MasterService.java:1216) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:984) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[?:?]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[?:?]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[?:?]

Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-security/x-pack-security-8.14.2.jar

at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92) ~[?:?]

at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106) ~[?:?]

at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]

at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:56) ~[?:?]

at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:171) ~[?:?]

at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99) ~[?:?]

at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1858) ~[?:?]

at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1491) ~[?:?]

at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:724) ~[?:?]

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:251) ~[?:?]

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:180) ~[?:?]

at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:345) ~[?:?]

at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:100) ~[?:?]

at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69) ~[?:?]

at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:168) ~[?:?]

at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getOrCreate(JarFileFactory.java:91) ~[?:?]

at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:117) ~[?:?]

at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:160) ~[?:?]

at org.elasticsearch.plugins.spi.SPIClassIterator.loadNextProfile(SPIClassIterator.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-8.14.2.jar:?]

... 26 more

Tried to reinstall Elastic Search and clean all old files and didn't work, the same problem occurred the next week
